# How to copy an area from a canvas into an image

Tags: java, canvas, swt, composite

I am trying to copy an area around the mouse cursor from my `Canvas` into an `Image` using the `gc.copyarea` method. Afterwards I want to paint that image onto a composite which appears after the mouse has been pressed for 1 second.

Below is my code so far:
In the `paintControl` Method of my canvas I copy the area to an image:

```
    img = new Image(display, 40, 40);
    gc.copyArea(img, mousePosition.x-20, mousePosition.y-20);
```

In the `paintControl` Method of my Composite I paint that image:

```
    if (img != null) {
        gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
```

The problem I am having is that only a very small part of the area is actually copied and painted onto the composite. Of the 40x40 pixel area, only an area of 10x20 pixel area in the bottom left corner is visible in the composite.

Example:[image]

The cursor is next to the top left corner of the compisite. Only a small part of the area around the cursor is painted onto the compisite

Question: How can I copy an area from my canvas and paint it onto another composite correctly? What did I do wrong in my Code?

Comment: The image that you created is 40x40 pixels, this size defines the rectangle that you can copy from the Canvas to the Composite. Also, are you sure that the mouse location is mapped correctly to the Canvas coodinates used in `copyArea()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trial and error I managed to get something working that supposedly comes close to what you want.

```
public class CopyArea {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    CopyArea copyArea = new CopyArea();
    copyArea.create();
    copyArea.run();
  }

  private Display display;
  private Image sourceImage;
  private Point canvasSize;
  private Shell shell;
  private Canvas source;
  private Canvas destination;
  private Point snippetOrigin;
  private Image snippet;

  CopyArea() {
    display = new Display();
    sourceImage = new Image( display, getClass().getResourceAsStream( "mona-lisa.jpeg" ) );
    canvasSize = new Point( sourceImage.getBounds().width, sourceImage.getBounds().height );
    shell = new Shell( display );
    source = new Canvas( shell, SWT.NONE );
    destination = new Canvas( shell, SWT.NONE );
  }

  void create() {
    shell.setLayout( new RowLayout() );
    source.setLayoutData( new RowData( canvasSize ) );
    source.addPaintListener( new PaintListener() {
      @Override
      public void paintControl( PaintEvent event ) {
        event.gc.drawImage( sourceImage, 0, 0 );
        if( snippetOrigin != null ) {
          snippet = new Image( display, 40, 40 );
          event.gc.copyArea( snippet, snippetOrigin.x, snippetOrigin.y );
          destination.redraw();
          snippetOrigin = null;
        }
      }
    } );
    source.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseDown( MouseEvent event ) {
        snippetOrigin = new Point( event.x, event.y );
        source.redraw();
      }
    } );
    destination.setLayoutData( new RowData( canvasSize ) );
    destination.addPaintListener( new PaintListener() {
      @Override
      public void paintControl( PaintEvent event ) {
        event.gc.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_WHITE ) );
        event.gc.fillRectangle( event.gc.getClipping() );
        if( snippet != null ) {
          event.gc.drawImage( snippet, 0, 0 );
        }
      }
    } );
  }

  void run() {
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
      if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

The `sourceImage` is just a placeholder for your drawing code. The `source` Canvas listens to mouse-down events and then draws a 40x40 snippet of its client are to the `destination` Canvas. Note that I used Canvas in both cases, but Canvas and Composite should also work.

Here is how it works: The mouse-listeners stores the mouse location into `snippetOrigin` and triggers a repaint of the `source`. The paint-listener of `source` takes a partial screen-shot of what it just has drawn if requested (`snippetOrigin != null`) and then forces `destination` to redrawitself. The paint-listener of `destination` simple draws the `snippet` image if there is any.

The code deos not yet correctly clip the copied image. If you press the mouse in the lower right corner of the `source` Canvas, some of the shell`s trimming will be copied as well.

For brevity, the code does not dispose of the `snippet` image before reusing it (and may have other leaks).

If you own the drawing code that paints your equivalent of the `source` Canvas, I would rather refactor it so that arbitrary portions can be drawn and then call the code with appropriate parameters to draw on the `destination` widget.

Comment: Ok after reading your answer I saw my mistake. I first copied the area to the image and then drew the source image on the canvas. So of course there would be nothing to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, sample to get a copy of an canvas area and paste in an object

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

function copy() {
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);
}
```

in this case the copy was paste at the canvas destination as origin

try this reference

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

and this it the API reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData